# Error "NO Client tried to access nonexistent namespace" while creating folder using Jakarta Mail 2.0.0

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

I'm trying create a folder under Inbox, using Jakarta Mail 2.0.0 , this is debug output :

```
A2 CREATE "Created folder - 2021-03-23"
A2 NO Client tried to access nonexistent namespace. (Mailbox name should probably be prefixed with: INBOX.) (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

Please advise how I can set a prefix ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with javax.mail
When I got this exception I did folder creation this way:

```java
    URLName url = new URLName("imaps", host, 993, "INBOX", email, password);
    Store store = session.getStore(url);
    store.connect();
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder(url);
    Folder myFolder = store.getFolder("MyNewFolder");
```

And whenever I tried to move something from inbox to myFolder folder I got the error you mentioned. As well as I could not create the folder itself (it did not throw exception just returned false). Side note that this method worked with gmail for some reason without throwing any exception, but not with any other imap hosts.

So what I did instead of
`store.getFolder("MyNewFolder");`
I used
`Folder myFolder = inbox.getFolder("MyFolder");`

So basically I got the Folder reference via inbox folder instead of getting from session.

I have no idea if jakarta mail works the same way or not, but I'll leave my solution here because I found nothing related to this at all and it might be helpful for someone.